# Datepicker Bootstrap não funciona

Tags: html, bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Tenho um Datepicker do bootstrap, mas quando clico no botão ao lado da caixa de texto, não aparece aquele calendário.

Achei que pudesse ser algum link ou script faltando, mas eu sempre acho só o código do datepicker sem os links que ele precisa fazer.

Segue o danadinho:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="utf-8">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

    <title>PSA-Formações</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    body {

        background-color: #dcdcdc;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 style="
                    margin-top:100px;">Cadastro de Turmas</h1>
                <p> </p>
                <p class="lead"></p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateT.php">

                       <!-- Olha ele aqui -->

                        <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                        <label>Data:</label>
                                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                $(function () {
                                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
    <!-- /.container -->
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Na função `$('#datetimepicker1')` não existe um elemento com id _datetimepicker1_

Comment: Alterei, mas ainda não funciona :/

Comment: Outra coisa, acho que eu não preciso de um datetime e sim somente um date. Dá pra transformar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faz um debug pelo navegador pressione <kbd>F12</kbd> guia console para verificar se tem algum erro JavaScript, porque, acabei de gerar um teste e funcionou, mas, no final desse HTML tem dois JavaScript que não tenho como testar, observe o exemplo minimo rodando:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h1 style="
                    margin-top:100px;">Cadastro de Turmas</h1>
      <p> </p>
      <p class="lead"></p>
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateT.php">

          <!-- Olha ele aqui -->

          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class='col-sm-12'>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <label>Data:</label>
                    <input type='text' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                });
              </script>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.container -->
```

Se ainda quiser formata a data é só ir no input e colocar um paramentro (`data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY"`), ***exemplo***:

```
<input type='text' data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Ah, eu copiei o seu código e apaguei meus scripts do fim da página e funcionou! Deixa eu fazer uma pergunta extra. Se eu quisesse transformar esse datetimepicker em só datepicker?

Comment: @MarianaFerreira é na configuração do input, edite a resposta para exemplificar melhor.

Comment: Menino, você é incrível!